# Change the size of input with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have the following input:

```
<input id="input_2_2" 
       class="medium" 
       type="file" 
       tabindex="4" 
       size="20" 
       value="" 
       name="input_2">
```

I don't have access to the HTML therefore I would like to apply jQuery to change the size to "60".

Please can someone help?

Comment: Please read the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
$('#input_2_2').attr('size',60);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$("#input_2_2").attr("size", "60");
```

I believe that should work..

Answer (score 2):

`$("input_2_2").attr("size", "60");`

Comment: I think Your selector is wrong. This will select an element of type "input_2_2" which is not defined in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

use [**attr();**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

like this:

`<input id="input_2_2" class="medium" type="file" tabindex="4" size="20" value="" name="input_2">`

`$("#input_2_2").attr("size","60");`

or, you can just set the `width` of the element, in my opinion it's better.

Answer (score 0):

I used [`.prop`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$('#input_2_2').prop('size',60);
```

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.